# How to infer the Generics type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class that I use every time I need to return something in my APIs.

```
    public class OperResult<T>
    {
        public bool Ok { get; private set; }
        public T Data { get; private set; }

        // Failed result (Ok: false)
        public string ErrorCode { get; private set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
       
        public static OperResult<T> Success(T data)
        {
            return new OperResult<T>(data);
        }

        public static OperResult<T> Error(string message, string code = null)
        {
            return new OperResult<T>(message, code);
        }

        private OperResult(T data = default(T))
        {
            Data = data;
            Ok = true;
        }
        private OperResult(string message, string code = null)
        {
            ErrorCode = code;
            ErrorMessage = message;
            Ok = false;
        }
    }
```

And one that doesn't have generics

```
    public class OperResult
    {
        public string ErrorCode { get; private set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
        public object Data { get; private set; }
        public bool Ok { get; private set; }
        
        public static OperResult Success(object data = null)
        {
            return new OperResult(data);
        }

        public static OperResult Error(string message, string code = null)
        {
            return new OperResult(message, code);
        }

        private OperResult(object data)
        {
            Data = data;
            Ok = true;
        }
        private OperResult(string message, string code = null)
        {
            ErrorCode = code;
            ErrorMessage = message;
            Ok = false;
        }
    }
```

In every API response, I return these objects so I know the data and the status of the operation.

```
        public async Task<OperResult<IEnumerable<string>>> GetLocationNames()
        {
            var locations = await locationService.GetAll(AuthState);
            if (location != null)
               return OperResult<IEnumerable<string>>.Success(locations.Select(u => u.name));
            else
               return OperResult<IEnumerable<string>>.Error("No location data found");

        }
```

I would like to be able not to write the Generics part every time I use it.
Maybe something like:

```
        public async Task<OperResult<IEnumerable<string>>> GetLocationNames()
        {
            var locations = await locationService.GetAll(AuthState);
            if (location != null)
               return OperResult.Success(locations.Select(u => u.name)); // infer <IEnumerable<string>>
            else
               return OperResult.Error("No location data found"); // here too

        }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: maybe impossible for `Error`

Comment: Is there a reason for having private constructors called by a static public method instead of just having public constructors and using them in your code to create a new OperResult for success/failure before returning?

Comment: the compiler needs a way to infer the type `T` of `OperResult<T>`, so you will need to specify the generic part. your second example - `OperResult` however, the compiler already know its exact type `object` so you dont have to explain it to the compiler. you could also use `OperResult<object>`, none stops you.

Comment: @CristianTeodorov I use the static constructors for convenience only. I don't think that this will be the problem but i could remove them if you have something on your mind

Comment: @BagusTesa I have implement it twice so i can use it in a simpler way such as `OperResult.Success`. I wanted to skip using the much longer `OperResult<Object>.Success`

Comment: well, you could put the static generation code somewhere (call it helper or factory or whatever your heart desire) outside the `OperResult<T>` made and declare them as such: `public static OperResult<T> Make<T>(T data)`. it will work for "success" given it can infer the `T` from the parameter. however, it doesnt work for "error" as `T` isnt part of the parameter and you have to specify it.

Comment: @MenelaosVergis Rather than implementing twice you can use use inheritance: `OperResult: OperResult<object>`

Answer (score 3):

First, I noticed that the non-generic `OperResult` can inherit from `OperResult<object>`. I recommend doing that to avoid code duplication.

The below is inspired by [Simulating Return Type Inference in C#](https://tyrrrz.me/blog/return-type-inference).

Create a `DelayedResult<T>` as a wrapper for some value. This will be useful later on:

```
public readonly struct DelayedResult<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }

    public DelayedResult(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

In the non-generic `OperResult`, create an `Error` and a generic `Success` method. These are what clients will use to create `OperResult<T>` and `OperResult`s. Note that these will return the `DelayedResult` declared earlier:

```
public static DelayedResult<T> Success<T>(T ok) =>
    new DelayedResult<T>(ok);

public static DelayedResult<Error> Error(string error, string code = null) =>
    new DelayedResult<Error>(new Error(error, code));
```

where `Error` is just a simple type containing the error and code. It could be as simple as a record:

```
record Error(string Message, string Code);
```

In `OperResult<T>`, create implicit conversion operators that converts from `DelayedResult` to actual `OperResult<T>`s:

```
public static implicit operator OperResult<T>(DelayedResult<T> ok) =>
    new OperResult<T>(ok.Value);

public static implicit operator OperResult<T>(DelayedResult<Error> error) =>
    new OperResult<T>(error.Value.Message, error.Value.Code);
```

Note that you should never have  `OperResult<Error>` (doesn’t make sense anyway), otherwise the above two overloads will be ambiguous.

In the non-generic `OperResult`, you can also have:

```
public static implicit operator OperResult(DelayedResult<object> ok) =>
    new OperResult(ok.Value);

public static implicit operator OperResult(DelayedResult<Error> error) =>
    new OperResult(error.Value.Msg, error.Value.Code);
```

Now you can do

```
    public async Task<OperResult<IEnumerable<string>>> GetLocationNames()
    {
        var locations = await locationService.GetAll(AuthState);
        if (location != null)
           return OperResult.Success(locations.Select(u => u.name));
        else
           return OperResult.Error("No location data found");

    }
```

Full code:

```
public record Error(string Message, string Code);
public readonly struct DelayedResult<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }

    public DelayedResult(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class OperResult: OperResult<object>
{
    private OperResult(object data) : base(data) {}
    private OperResult(string message, string code = null): base(message, code) {}

    public static implicit operator OperResult(DelayedResult<object> ok) =>
        new OperResult(ok.Value);

    public static implicit operator OperResult(DelayedResult<Error> error) =>
        new OperResult(error.Value.Message, error.Value.Code);

    public static DelayedResult<T> Success<T>(T ok) =>
        new DelayedResult<T>(ok);

    public static DelayedResult<Error> Error(string message, string code = null) =>
        new DelayedResult<Error>(new Error(message, code));
}

public class OperResult<T>
{
    public bool Ok { get; private set; }
    public T Data { get; private set; }
    public string ErrorCode { get; private set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator OperResult<T>(DelayedResult<T> ok) =>
        new OperResult<T>(ok.Value);

    public static implicit operator OperResult<T>(DelayedResult<Error> error) =>
        new OperResult<T>(error.Value.Message, error.Value.Code);


    protected OperResult(T data = default(T))
    {
        Data = data;
        Ok = true;
    }
    protected OperResult(string message, string code = null)
    {
        ErrorCode = code;
        ErrorMessage = message;
        Ok = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling static from `OperResult<T>` will always require you to specify the generic part. However, if its a method that returns `OperResult<T>` from different class, it may infer the generic via method parameters (assuming `OperResult<T>` constructor is public):

```
public static class OperHelper
{
    public static OperResult<T> Success<T>(T data)
    {
        return new OperResult<T>(data);
    }
}
```

The method above can be called by `OperHelper.Create(myPayload)`. However, it relies on the fact that `myPayload` can be used to infer what type is `T`. This will allow you to handle the "success" part of the `OperResult`.

The proposed solution below involves breaking down the `OperResult<T>` into several class. It assumes the following:

- "Error" always have the `bool Ok` property as `false` and vice versa
- "Error" doesnt need to bring payload/data

First, you have class `OperResult`, it only holds the contract for `bool Ok`:

```
public abstract class OperResult
{
    public abstract bool Ok { get; }
}
```

Then, we extend the `OperResult` into two - `OperSuccess` and `OperError`:

```
public class OperSuccess<T> : OperResult
{
    public override bool Ok { get { return true;} }
    public T Data { get; private set; }
    
    public OperSuccess(T data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }
}


public class OperError : OperResult
{
    public override bool Ok { get { return false;} }
    public string ErrorCode { get; private set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
    
    public OperError(string message, string code = null)
    {
        this.ErrorCode = code;
        this.ErrorMessage = message;
    }
}
```

This way, we can expand our `OperHelper` into accomodating the "error" part.

```
public static class OperHelper
{
    public static OperSuccess<T> Success<T>(T data)
    {
        return new OperSuccess<T>(data);
    }
    
    public static OperError Error(string message, string code = null)
    {
        return new OperError(message, code);
    }
}
```

This way, it allow us to call either `OperHelper.Success(myObject)` or `OperHelper.Error("my error message")`.

Note:

- Yes, none stops you from creating either `OperSuccess` and `OperError` manually
- Yes, it works on .Net 4.7